# Setup Enviroment Sql server 2008 R2, BIDS, needing samples

Tags: sql-server-2008, business-intelligence, bids

I have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 SP3 express edition 64 bits, and the Advanced Services for BIDS. Following an Ebook tutorial I need a SQL Server AdventureWorksDW 2008 R2 sample database as the basis for building an SSAS cube".

I am supposed to find "samples" after installattion in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
Server\100\Tools\" but I have in this dir is "binn". Do I need to download these files separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These samples are now a separate [download](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/) from Codeplex.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will see if which one I need. Marked as answer.